# $\pi^4+\pi^5 < e^6 $

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, inequality

Any idea about this inequality:

$$\large \pi^4+\pi^5<e^6$$

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Confirmed using WolframAlpha; but if there's actually a algebraic (or whatever) way **without the use of a calculator** to confirm this, I'll definitely want to know!